# Can't Delete Items on SharePoint through Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint

so I had finished making my sites. One issue one of my peers brought up was that if using Internet Explorer, you cannot delete anything.

For example, I can create items just fine in Internet Explorer. In my site contents I created a new custom list called "test". I click on the ellipses in the top right of the app, and click remove and nothing happens, a small grey box outlines the ellipses and the web app stays there.

[image]

Now if I want to delete that web app, I must open up Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome.

What is causing this? And how do I fix it? I have not been able to find anything online about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which version of the IE browser you are using for making this test, I try to test the issue using IE 11 and found that I am able to remove the list.

Test result:

[image]

I suggest you logout from SharePoint and clear the cache for this site. Restart the IE browser. See whether it helps to fix this issue.

Make sure that you are having enough rights to delete the list and there are no permissions set for this list to prevent users from deleting this list.

I suggest you try this [alternative approach](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-a-list-2a7bca5b-b8fd-4e5b-8f4b-2ac034f3070d#Experience=Modern) to delete the list.

If the issue persists, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/unable-to-delete-files) may help to get some additional information to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this has nothing to do with my JS. I had looked into Babel to see if maybe I need to compile into an older form of JS, but that isn't the issue. It is within IE itself. Basically IE is giving out as time moves forward. All other browsers are far more superior.